How do I burn a debian distribution ISO into a bootable disk using Fedora's command-line tools?
I've been a Fedora user "since forever" (Red Hat v1.1) but, frustrated by some issues I can't ignore, I am interested in trying both Debian and Ubuntu. Step zero was to download the latest releases. I picked Debian 12.7.0 as my first to try. However, in the past I was using a Windows box to burn DVDs for no good reason but familiarity. ... And thus I'd never had to actually burn the DVD on Linux before.
Following the directions from various sources here, I started with:
# wodim -v dev='/dev/sg2' -eject debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

Whir-whir-whir went the DVD with lots of progress reported but a cup of coffee or so later I got some errors pertaining to "fixating" the disk, namely:
Fixating...
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), flush cache scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 00 40 A0 03 21 04 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x21 Qual 0x04 (logical block address out of range) [No matching qualifier] Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 137.712s timeout 120s
Trouble flushing the cache
wodim: Cannot fixate disk.
Fixating time:  137.712s
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), prevent/allow medium removal scsi sendcmd: fatal error
CDB:  1E 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), start/stop unit scsi sendcmd: fatal error
CDB:  1B 00 00 00 02 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
wodim: Cannot eject media.
wodim: fifo had 62911 puts and 62911 gets.
wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 7253 times full, min fill was 34%.

Using man I found -fix, and tried it, but it didn't work either, as can be seen here - a VERY different kind of error:
# wodim -v dev='/dev/sg2' -fix
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '/dev/sg2'
devname: '/dev/sg2'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.36
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
wodim: Cannot do inquiry for CD/DVD-Recorder.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), test unit ready scsi sendcmd: fatal error
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s

So, I figured I'd try dd since several question/answer entries here strongly implied dd can make a bootable DVD, just watch out for sync issues, so, this:
# dd if=debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/sg2 bs=4M && sync

But... It doesn't do anything! And from that I did research and found this entry which says dd used to be able to do this and for some unknown but likely (in my view) silly reason, the ability was removed?! However, that is disputed. Hmmm...
This system usually makes the cd/dvd drive available on /dev/cdrom and to read I do something like # mount /dev/cdrom /mounts/cd0 and then I have the contents available on /mounts/cd0. But trying /dev/cdrom didn't do anything either:
# dd if=debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/cdrom bs=4M && sync

No Joy.
I've read several other entries on stack exchange sites, such as this one or this one, among others, but didn't find a solution...
MAYBE I just had a media error and need to retry the original command? I hate to waste disks but...
On suggestion, I tried:
# wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject -sao debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
wodim: Cannot do inquiry for CD/DVD-Recorder.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), test unit ready scsi sendcmd: fatal error
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 200s

Hmmm... There is a /dev/sr0 entry...
I WENT TO A DIFFERENT MACHINE...
Same operating system, same brand drive, etc, and I ran the command from the answer below and it wrote a disk.
IMPORTANTLY along the way I noted the software - wodim - said:
Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.

Upon reading that I instantly deduced the drives MAY be the same brand (ASUS) but not the same type, or maybe there's a motherboard difference? I don't know.
Since I had copied and pasted the entire output from the original "unfixated" run, I can say it wasn't in there. However, it was in this new SUCCESSFUL run - that boots propertly! - so ... Apparently what I needed to have found was maybe this article.
Aren't computers fun?

The Debian CD FAQ gives commands to use with a variety of CD/DVD writing tools. With wodim, the suggested command is
wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject -sao debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

Note that this uses the regular SCSI device rather than the generic one used in your attempt.
You’ll need a new disc as well, unless you used a rewritable disc.
I suspect the common approach nowadays is to use USB drives rather than actual optical media; the ISO files provided by Debian work fine on USB sticks.
As far as I’m aware, dd has never been able to write to DVDs other than DVD-RAM.

Direct writing is also supported for DVD+RW discs (but not DVD-RW).

@u1686_grawity Please define "Direct writing". ... And Stephen, good try but look at my updated entry: I think it's saying that /dev/sr0 doesn't exist...

You might find my latest update to the Q interesting... CONFIRMED your command; it's booted just fine. But something else is / was going on on that box...
